QGIS python configuration LayoutTable
I have a problem when I import layout template in QGIS project with Layout Attribute Table. In template I have two frames (tabela1 and tabela2) for one table which is connect to layer "VOZLISCA". Settings of attributes are shown on picture below.

When template is imported into project I lost connection of table to the layer and settings of attributes. I would like to repair them with Python code.
project = QgsProject().instance()
layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('Protokol')  

#add layout Protoko if doesnt exist
if layout == None:
    layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
    context = QgsReadWriteContext()
    layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
    template_path = os.path.join(self.plugin_dir, 'layout','Protokol.qpt')
    template_file = open(template_path, 'r+', encoding='utf-8')
    content = template_file.read()
    template_file.close()
    document = QDomDocument()
    document.setContent(content)
    layout.loadFromTemplate(document, context)
    layout_name = 'Protokol'
    layout.setName(layout_name)
    layout_manager.addLayout(layout)

layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('Protokol')


#find both table
AttributeTable1 = layout.itemById('tabela1') 
print('AttributeTable1: ',AttributeTable1)

layoutItemAttributeTable = AttributeTable1.multiFrame()
print('LayoutItemAttributeTable ', layoutItemAttributeTable)

AttributeTable2 = layout.itemById('tabela2') 
print('AttributeTable2: ', AttributeTable2)

layoutItemAttributeTable = AttributeTable2.multiFrame()
print('LayoutItemAttributeTable ', layoutItemAttributeTable)

#correct connection to the layer
existingLayer = project.mapLayersByName('VOZLISCA')[0]
layoutItemAttributeTable.setVectorLayer(existingLayer)

#Correct atribute settings
layoutItemAttributeTable.setTableContents(["naziv","distTP","resisTP"])
layoutItemAttributeTable.setColumnWidths([60,13,19])
layoutItemAttributeTable.setHeaders(['Naziv','Dis [m]','Zcalc [ohm]'])
layout.refresh()

"""
#This works but I cant change Headers and ColumnWidths
layoutItemAttributeTable.setVectorLayer(existingLayer)
layoutItemAttributeTable.setDisplayedFields(["naziv","distTP","resisTP"],True)
layout.refresh()
"""

These are print results:
AttributeTable1:  <qgis._core.QgsLayoutFrame object at 0x0000021A0D133770>
LayoutItemAttributeTable  <qgis._core.QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable object at 0x0000021A0D133C80>
AttributeTable2:  <qgis._core.QgsLayoutFrame object at 0x0000021A0D133D10>
LayoutItemAttributeTable  <qgis._core.QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable object at 0x0000021A0D133C80>
I get this Error:
AttributeError: 'QgsLayoutItemAttributeTable' object has no attribute 'setTableContents'. Did you mean: 'getTableContents'?
Does anybody have a solution how to change columns settings in layout attribute table with Python code like I have in template?

Either of the answers here can help you change the column headers.

@Ben W thank you for your hint. It was a part of solution for my problem.

No problem. If you found that answer helpful you could consider upvoting it (that's how this site works) ;-)

@Ben W thank you for your hint. It was a part of solution for my problem. The finaly code for importing layout template and customizing layout table is:
    #add layout Protoko if doesnt exist
    if layout == None:
        layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
        context = QgsReadWriteContext()
        layout_manager = project.layoutManager()
        template_path = os.path.join(self.plugin_dir, 'layout','Protokol.qpt')
        template_file = open(template_path, 'r+', encoding='utf-8')
        content = template_file.read()
        template_file.close()
        document = QDomDocument()
        document.setContent(content)
        layout.loadFromTemplate(document, context)
        layout_name = 'Protokol'
        layout.setName(layout_name)
        layout_manager.addLayout(layout)
  
    layout = project.layoutManager().layoutByName('Protokol')
    
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('VOZLISCA')[0]
   
    #find both table
    AttributeTable1 = layout.itemById('tabela1') 
    print('AttributeTable1: ',AttributeTable1)
    
    layoutItemAttributeTable = AttributeTable1.multiFrame()
    print('LayoutItemAttributeTable ', layoutItemAttributeTable)
    
    AttributeTable2 = layout.itemById('tabela2') 
    print('AttributeTable2: ', AttributeTable2)
    
    layoutItemAttributeTable = AttributeTable2.multiFrame()
    print('LayoutItemAttributeTable ', layoutItemAttributeTable)
    
    #correct connection to the layer
    existingLayer = project.mapLayersByName('VOZLISCA')[0]
    layoutItemAttributeTable.setVectorLayer(existingLayer)

    
    #corect column atributes, width, header
    layoutItemAttributeTable.setVectorLayer(existingLayer)
    layoutItemAttributeTable.setDisplayedFields(["naziv","distTP","resisTP","distTP","distTP","distTP","distTP","distTP","distTP"],True)
    
    attributes = ["naziv","distTP",'2*"resisTP"',None,None,None,None,None,None]
    headers = ['Naziv','Dis [m]','Zcalc [ohm]', 'Z L1-L1','Z L1-L3', 'Z L2-L3', 'Z L1-N', 'Z L2-N', 'Z L3-N']
    widths = [60,13,19,12,12,12,12,12,12]
    
    cols = layoutItemAttributeTable.columns()
    new_cols = [col.clone() for col in cols]
    
    for i, cloned_col in enumerate(new_cols):
        cloned_col.setAttribute(attributes[i])
        cloned_col.setHeading(headers[i])
        cloned_col.setWidth(widths[i])
        
    layoutItemAttributeTable.setColumns(new_cols)
    layout.refresh()

